# Master branch of the repository didn't keep all the changes - How is it possible?

Tags: git

Here is a list of all commits on the master branch of my gitlab repository (remote server).

```
commit #5 - user#1
commit #4 - user#3
commit #3 - user#2
commit #2 - user#1
commit #1 - user#1
```

I just realized that commit#5 doesn't have the changes made in commit #4 and commit #3.  No forced commits have been made by user#1.  How come this happened?

I'm clueless

p.s. It says that the parent of commit#5, commit#4 and commit#3 is commit#2.  commit#1 is the parent of commit#2.  What does it mean?

Comment: How are you ascertaining that commit 5 is missing the change?

Comment: Commits don't contain changes from other commits. What makes you think changes are missing?

Comment: @merlin2011 I downloaded all the files from commit#5 directly from the gitlab server, changes from commit #3 and #4 are not there.  This is just a simplification, by the way; same thing happened multiple times in an history of 150 commits

Comment: Did commit #5 revert the changes that were in #3 and #4?

Comment: @BJMyers Yes! Exactly!

Comment: Did commit#5 encounter merge conflicts (either pull-merge or merge-to-master)? It may have been resolved (carelessly) by ignoring "their" changes and just using "mine".

Comment: @GinoMempin  No conflicts or warnings of any sort.  That's why I don't understand!  I thought that if there's no conflict, everything is alright.

Comment: It sounds like somebody did a bad merge.

Comment: @merlin2011 And how does a bad merge happen? Sorry if my question is dumb.

Comment: Exactly as described in the earlier comment. They saw a conflict and kept their own changes. Then pushed. Perhaps the conflict was during a rebase.

Comment: @merlin2011  I doubt there were any "bad merge". Any other explanation possible?

Comment: I think I meant a bad rebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parent of #5 is #2, and the parent of #4 is #2, and the parent of #3 is #2, while the parent of #2 is #1, then you have a series of commits that we can draw like this, with the older commits on the left and the newer ones on the right:

```
     3
    /
1--2--4
    \
     5
```

Commits 3, 4, and 5 are *siblings*: they're all children of commit #2.  But #4 is not a *descendant* of #3, for instance, so it's kind of unreasonable to expect #4 to bear the scars that #3 accumulated. :-)

We would also call all of 3, 4, and 5 *branches*, branching off from 2.  The history of #3 would be (1, 2, 3); the history of #4 would be (1, 2, 4); and the history of #5 would be (1, 2, 5).  You have not shown us the names of these three branches, but they probably do have names.  **Edit**: unless, that is, they come together again.  For instance, suppose that there are subsequent merges:

```
     3----
    /     \
1--2--4--M34--M5--...   <-- master
    \         /
     5--------
```

Now the relationships are rather tangled, and you need a competent graph viewer (such as `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` or `gitk --all`) to see them.

If all you do is retrieve source images from a server:

> I downloaded all the files from commit#5 directly from the gitlab server ...

then you will never be able to see the *relationships* between these commits.  To see relationships, you should *clone the repository*.  This gives you a new repository that, at least for the moment, is a near-exact copy of the one you cloned from.  You can then use various Git commands to inspect your copy, which, being reasonably faithful to the original, will also tell you useful things about the original.

(A clone is deliberately not an *exact* copy, so that, among other things, you can tell that it's the clone, and so that you can work on it.  You *can* make an exact copy, but doing so gives you a clone you should not work on, in general—you should use it only to gather updates from its original, so that it remains an exact copy.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! ///

You have not shown us the names of these three branches ===> Everything is on the same branch: the master branch

/// then you will never be able to see the relationships between these commits. ====>  I can see them with gitlab https://prnt.sc/fzescm

Comment: How can you have multiple branches on the master branch?  Can you have branches within a branch?

Comment: You *can* have branches within a branch, as long as they come together again in the end so that they form a single branch. I cannot see much on your link though—just one hash ID.

Comment: Ah thanks! This explain some things!  /// The screen shot is only to show you I can see parents through web access (without cloning the repo). https://prnt.sc/fzeuyb

Comment: See edit and additional graph bits. This kind of thing is visually obvious with a good graph viewer, but good graph viewers are hard to construct. The ones in command-line Git (`git log ... --graph` and `gitk`) are not bad, though by no means perfect.

Comment: Do you have a link that explains how to merge all the sub-branches? Thanks

Comment: If—again, I can't actually *see* them myself, so just "if"—they look like the diagram I drew, they are already merged. They were just merged incorrectly, by whoever merged them. You would need to re-do some or all of the work. Probably the simplest would be to use `git cherry-pick` to turn the "lost" commits into change-sets and re-apply them as new commits, advancing the current tip of the branch.